# Dual of the complexification is complexification of the dual

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure if this question was asked already, but I couldn't find it anyway.

If $V$ is a real vector space. The complexification is defined as $V_\mathbb{C} := V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$. Now there also is the dual of the complexifcation, i.e. $(V_\mathbb{C})^*$ and according to Huybrechts it is
$\begin{align*} (V_\mathbb{C})^* = \hom_\mathbb{R}(V,\mathbb{C}) = (V^*)_\mathbb{C} \end{align*}$.

Can somebody maybe explain the first equality to me? In my opinion it should be $(V_\mathbb{C})^* = \hom_\mathbb{C}(V_\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{C})$ because $V_\mathbb{C}$ is a complex vector space, but this clearly isn't the same as the equality Huybrechts is saying to be true. Also I am struggling with the same equalities for $(V^{1,0})^*$ and $(V^*)^{1,0}$ but the reason for this could be that I do not understand how the first equality comes to be true.

I would appreciate any help on this.

EDIT: Of course I should mention that $V$ is equipped with an almost complex structure $I$ in order for the second "question" to be meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it is $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C}$), not $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V_{\mathbb{C}},\mathbb{C})$. Of course by definition we have $(V_{\mathbb{C}})^*=\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V_{\mathbb{C}},\mathbb{C})$. So we have to show the following equality:

$\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})=\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V_{\mathbb{C}},\mathbb{C})$

To be precise, the two spaces are not equal by set theory, but there is a very natural isomorphism between them. Note that if $\varphi\in\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})$ then $\varphi$ can be "extended" to a complex linear transformation $\psi:V_{\mathbb{C}}\to\mathbb{C}$. To be precise, the map $f:V\times\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ given by $f(v,z)=z\cdot\varphi(v)$ is clearly a bilinear map over $\mathbb{R}$, and so it defines an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $\psi:V\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ which satisfies $\psi(v\otimes z)=z\cdot\varphi(v)$. But you can easily check that $\psi$ is even a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map, i.e an element of $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V_{\mathbb{C}},\mathbb{C}$).

Conversely, if $\psi:V_{\mathbb{C}}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map, then you can define $\varphi:V\to\mathbb{C}$ by $\varphi(v)=\psi(v\otimes 1)$. Again, it is easily checked that $\varphi\in\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})$.

Also, the correspondences which I defined between $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V_{\mathbb{C}},\mathbb{C})$ are inverses of each other, i.e they define an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im not quite sure if I get this right. If I have an $\mathbb{R}$-linear mapping $\varphi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ I can extend it to an $\mathbb{R}$ linear mapping $\Psi: V_\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by having $\Psi(v \otimes z) = z \cdot \varphi(z)$.
Now You say that this is in fact $\mathbb{C}$-linear, is that correct?

Comment: @danra01 Yes. The universal property of the tensor product only tells us this is a linear map over $\mathbb{R}$. You need to check by hand that it even preserves multiplication by complex scalars, i.e it is linear even over $\mathbb{C}$. But that is just an easy computation.

Comment: Is the $\mathbb{C}$ linearity because of $\psi(v \otimes (\lambda\cdot z))= \lambda \cdot z \cdot \varphi(z)$?

Comment: @danra01 Yes. I would add the step $\psi(\lambda(v\otimes z))=\psi(v\otimes \lambda z)=\lambda z\cdot\varphi(v)=\lambda\psi(v\otimes z)$. By the way, not every element in the tensor product is a simple tensor. But it is enough to check linearity only on such elements, from this it follows linearity works over sums of simple tensors as well.

Comment: But what about $(V^{1,0})^* = \hom_\mathbb{C}(V^{1,0}, \mathbb{C})$ and $(V^*)^{1,0} = \{f \in \hom_\mathbb{R}(V, \mathbb{C})\vert f(I(v)) = if(v) \}$ then. How could one explain these two to be equal? 
EDIT: Of course I should mention that $V$ has an almost complex structure $I$ then.

Comment: @danra01 Can you write the definition of $V^{1,0}$? I don't recall such notation.

Comment: If I have an almost complex structure I on $V$ this can be linearly extended to $I_\mathbb{C}: V_\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ now one can define $V^{1,0}:= \{v \in V_\mathbb{C} \mid I_\mathbb{C} (v) = -iv\}.$

Comment: @Mark Did u mean to say $Hom_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C}) = Hom_{\mathbb{C}}(V_{\mathbb{C}},\mathbb{C})$ as a complex vector space? If so, I feel a bit confused about it because from my understanding, the space $Hom_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ as indicated in the subscript, and it would be a strange to say two vector spaces are isomorphic while they are not over the same field. Would you mind enlightening me on this? Thanks

Comment: @Eric Actually, $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})$ is even a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, with the scalar multiplication being defined by $(\lambda\varphi)(v)=\lambda\cdot\varphi(v)$. It indeed makes no sense to put $\lambda$ inside $\varphi$, because $V$ is only a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. But you can multiply $\varphi(v)$ by a complex constant as well. The map $\lambda\varphi$ that I defined is again an element of $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})$, as you can check.

Comment: @Mark Got you! Thanks a lot! So the subscript $\mathbb{R}$ in $Hom_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})$ merely indicates the linear maps in $Hom_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linear and has noting to do with the field over which $Hom_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})$ would be, right?

Comment: @Eric Yes, the elements of $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,\mathbb{C})$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps $V\to\mathbb{C}$. (again, there is no possible meaning to $\mathbb{C}$-linear maps here, because $V$ is not a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$) And as I explained, this set can be turned into a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

In categorical terms,$\ast \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ is left adjoint to $\hom_{\mathbb{R}}(\ast, \mathbb{C})$ that is the reason why, but at this level you'll need to work with adequate tools.

So you have your complexification $V_\mathbb{C}$, its dual is $V_\mathbb{C}^* = \hom_\mathbb{C} (V_\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$, you need to show that $\hom_\mathbb{C} (V_\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C}) \simeq \hom_\mathbb{\mathbb{R}} (V,\mathbb{C})$ as $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces.

We use the second one because it is more convenient and gives a more "natural result".

If you want to go further, try to read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction .